# How to handle date and time with PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I need to do a little bit more complicated calculations with time and date values from my MySQL database with PHP.

I need to add or substract different values from a given date.

For example:

- Substracting 1 Month
- Substracting 30 Days
- Substracting 4 Weeks
- Adding 4 Month
- Adding 3 Month
- Adding 90 Days
- Adding 2 Years

Please note that there is a difference between substracting 1 Month, 4 Weeks or 30 Days.

What's the preferred way of doing this? Is there any clever library or can I do this with PHP's own functions?

Answer (score 7):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

You can add a second parameter to make it add to given time:

```
echo strtotime("+1 week",$timestamp)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of PHP5's `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects.

```
$now = new DateTime();

// 30 days ago
$now->sub(new DateInterval("P30D");

// 1 week ago
$now->sub(new DateInterval("P1W");

// 2 years from now
$now->add(new DateInterval("P1Y");
```

For a list of interval codes, see [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

Comment: +1 But note that this is just for php5.3 -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Comment: You can use modify() method of DateTime in 5.2

Answer (score 4):

Since PHP 5.2 you have the DateTime object.
You can do:

```
$date = new DateTime; // now
$date->modify('1 month ago');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Check [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for the complete sintax.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function [strtotime](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is very powerful in this regard.

For example:

```
// 1 month ago
$date = strtotime('-1 month');

// 30 days ago
$date = strototime('-30 days');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

$date will now be '2000-01-11'.

You can also use `date_sub` to subtract an amount of time.

More here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `strtotime()` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Also note that you can use the second parameter to dictate when to start from.

```
strtotime('+1 day', mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```

Answer (score 0):

try Pear Date library. Very powerful and flexible, with period adding capabilities. It does exactly what you want.

http://pear.php.net/Date

We use it in a very date-intensive web application, where we have to add a lot of time variable periods and calculate week number etc.

Answer (score 0):

look at this please [PHP dates](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/01/06/php-adding-and-subtracting-dates/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application you're going to want to either use the mysql datetime functions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

or strtotime like everyone else has said

Answer (score 0):

here's another suggestion. if you want to manipulate information from mysql, try using the date/time functions provided by mysql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)