# date/time format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have stored some data in mysql table me assign hime date
I use column id to type `timestamp` and it stores it like `'2013-02-12 21:42:45'`
I want to display it in this format `'Feb-2, 2013 9:42 PM'`
I use echo  `date('M-d ,Y',$create_date)` then it display `'Jan-01 ,1970'` and some `php eroor`.

Can someone help me

Comment: Try `date('M-d ,Y g:i a',strtotime($create_date)); `

Comment: jst display date not time

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle date and time with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101071/how-to-handle-date-and-time-with-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will output your desired date time format

```
<?php

//Output -- Feb-2, 2013 9:42 PM

$create_date = '2013-02-12 21:42:45';
echo date('M-d ,Y  g:i a',strtotime($create_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('M-d ,Y h:i A',strtotime($create_date))
```

try this strtotime convert time to time stamp and than you can format the date.

Comment: it jst display date format not time i also want to display time

Comment: edited answer please check

Answer (score 1):

use `DATE_FORMAT` if you want to do it through query,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-02-12 21:42:45','%b-%e, %Y %l:%i %p') result
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7458)

Comment: this is the right and quick way to format date if you are saving dates in database

Answer (score 0):

The [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function expects a timestamp as a second parameter. Use a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object to create the date and then the [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function.

```
$date = new DateTime($create_date);
echo $date->format('M-d ,Y g:i A');
```

Answer (score 0):

read the php file on date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

the second parameter of the date function is a unix timestamp, not a string (in any format)

so you want to convert your string to a timestamp (perhaps taking into consideration timezones) and then use that to reformat your date the way you want:

e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('<timezone of create_date>'); 
$date = date('M-d ,Y',strtotime($create_date)):
```

btw, this code will reset the default timezone of all subsequently executed php code... not sure if that matters in your use case

Answer (score 0):

check `$create_date` variable in your `date('M-d ,Y',$create_date)`. It is blank. No value is in this variable. for this it is showing 1970. assign date in `$create_date`.

Answer (score 0):

But if you need to reveal date in different formats, it would be better store it in the database as a timestamp. On php this value  can be generated by function time();